# Material Design - Toolbar and Tab Layout overlaps when scrolling

Tags: android, material-design

I'm designing a collapsing toolbar with tab layout. When collapsing toolbar layout is shown fully, it is shown as i want.

I want to make toolbar and tab bar fixed even if any scroll occurs. However when the appbar is collapsed, the toolbar and the tablayout overlaps as shown below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
                app:title="sample_pager_tabs_parallax_image"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I put the

```
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

inside TabLayout, however it does not work.

Putting the TabLayout out of CollapsingToolbarLayout solves the overlapping problem. However, i want to make parallax images shown in status bar, toolbar and tab bar as shown below :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the `TabLayout` out of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and move it into the `AppBarLayout`, this should solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/image"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
                    app:title="sample_pager_tabs_parallax_image"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: putting the TabLayout out of CollapsingToolbarLayout solves the overlapping problem. However, i want to make parallax images shown in status bar, toolbar and tab bar.

Comment: That wasn't the context of your original question, could you edit it to elaborate on what the desired outcome would be? really it should be a new question as you haven't mentioned it prior to this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of this issue just add this line in your toolbar layout.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these things:

1.put the `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` out of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and add it under `AppBarLayout`

2.Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout`

3.Also apply `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to the `Toolbar` to make it fix in top poition

Comment: putting the TabLayout out of CollapsingToolbarLayout solves the overlapping problem. However, i want to make parallax images shown in status bar, toolbar and tab bar.

Comment: i would suggest to put your imageview form collapsing toolbar layout to ....appbarlayout and make tablayout background transperant

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `Toolbar` height. Use `android:layout_height="104dp"` instead of `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`.
2. Remove attribute `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from `TabLayout`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
                app:title="sample_pager_tabs_parallax_image"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>    
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```